# Name Error: name 'QFileDialog' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, qfiledialog

I am working on coursework for computer science and can't work out why the piece of code isn't working. I am trying to connect a button that I've created in PyQt4 so that when it is pressed it shows a directory dialogue:

```
self.Browse_Button_1 = QtGui.QToolButton(self.tab)
    self.Browse_Button_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 30, 61, 20))
    self.Browse_Button_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Browse_Button_1"))
    file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
    self.Browse_Button_1.clicked.connect(self, file)
```

However every time I run the program I just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 194, in <module>
     ui = Ui_Dialog()
   File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 30, in __init__
     self.setupUi(self)
   File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 55, in setupUi
     file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
NameError: name 'QFileDialog' is not defined
```

Any help with the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

`QFileDialog` is in the [QtGui module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html), so you need to append that to beginning of your line, e.g.:

```
file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `QFileDialog` without the `QtGui` in front, you need to import it from the module (at the top of your file), with:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog
```

Or for Qt5 (note that in Qt5, `QFileDialog` moved to the `QtWidgets` module):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and unfortunately it comes up with the following error. I am using a school computer so it might just be that it's missing some kind of library.

Comment: `code`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 161, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
  File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 49, in setupUi
    file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
TypeError: QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(QWidget parent=None, str caption='', str directory='', QFileDialog.Options options=QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Dialog'

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 161, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
  File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 49, in setupUi
    file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
TypeError: QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(QWidget parent=None, str caption='', str directory='', QFileDialog.Options options=QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Dialog'`

Comment: @SirEctoplasm that error is complaining about the type of the `self` parameter. That needs to be a Qt type (`QWidget`) but it isn't. What is `self` in your example?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 161, in <module>
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
      File "D:\NEA Project\NEA_UI.py", line 49, in setupUi
        file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
    TypeError: QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(QWidget parent=None,     str caption='', str directory='', QFileDialog.Options     options=QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly): argument 1 has unexpected type     'Ui_Dialog'

Comment: Honestly I have no clue, i just watched a tutorial and it said you must have self in the code for it to work. sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: @SirEctoplasm I can read that :) But what *is* `Ui_Dialog`? Is it a `QWidget` type? If not, you need to pass in a parent window as the first parameter to your `QFileDialog` (e.g. your `QMainWindow` instance)

Comment: The `self` parameter there just needs to be something to 'own' the dialog. I normally pass in the main window, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm new to PyQt and don't really know how to use it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cYPjvXHs

I've separated the bit that I'm having trouble with

Comment: Change line 50 to:  `file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(Dialog, "Select Directory"))` — i.e. pass in Dialog as your first parameter.

Comment: Just fyi — naming variables with capital letters (`Dialog`) is a bad idea, this is used for classnames. e.g. `mywindow = QMainWindow()` here `mywindow` is the variable, `QMainWindow` is the class. Otherwise things will get very confusing!

Comment: The dialog pops up perfectly, except now the rest of the program doesn't turn on, it just straight to the dialog box

Comment: @SirEctoplasm See this http://pastebin.com/CxRVz31s  you need to wrap the dialog in a function (and also handle the result of it). In the paste I've done this for the first 'encrypt' button. I also change the input box to `QLineEdit` since it is better for this.

Comment: I'm not really following. i've changed the function to displayFileDialog1, but there are still errors. Sorry if this is frustrating

Comment: The pasted code works as is (there are multiple changes, not just the function). If you need more help with the code generally it'd be best to open a new question — this is going off topic for this one & comments aren't a good way to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. IT WORKS!

Comment: @SirEctoplasm No problem :) I've put another paste here: http://pastebin.com/521yC83s which highlights the changes. If you make the same changes for the other buttons/textboxes you should have it all working!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, one last question: how would i change the code so that the user can choose a file instead of a directory through that same dialog box?